# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I was following a tutorial on how to add google maps to a react/expo javascript project. I am new to the javascript language and have had a bug that I cannot find an answer to. when compiling the app I am given the error "***TypeError: Object(...) is not a function***". here is the link to the tutorial: *https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WZcxJGmLbSo&t*. Thank you.

The error is on the line 25 of the script:

````
22 | 
  23 | 
  24 | }
> 25 | export default function App() {
  26 |   const {isLoaded, LoadError} = UseLoadScript({
  27 |     googleMapsApiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY,
  28 |     libraries,```
````

Full script:

```
import React from 'react';

import {
  GoogleMap,
  UseLoadScript,
  Marker,
  InfoWindow,

} from "@react-google-maps/api";

const libraries = ["places"];
const mapContainerStyle = {
  width: "100vw",
  height: "100vh",

};

const center = {
  lat: 43.653225,
  lng: -79.383186


}
export default function App() {
  const {isLoaded, LoadError} = UseLoadScript({
    googleMapsApiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY,
    libraries,
  });
   
  
  if (LoadError) return "Error Loading maps";
  if (!isLoaded) return "Loading Maps";

  return <div> 

    <GoogleMap> 
      mapContainerStyle={mapContainerStyle} 
      zoom={8}
      center={center}
      </GoogleMap>
  </div>
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `import`(UseLoadScript) is wrong. Check here once [useLoadScript](https://react-google-maps-api-docs.netlify.app/#!/useLoadScript)

```
import { useLoadScript } from '@react-google-maps/api';
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve similar problem by upgrading React to v16.8+ to support the usage of hooks.